# Applications in different timezone from computer/

Tags: windows, time, time-zone

My computer time and timezone are set correctly but various applications seem to be independently set to different timezones. See screenshot below which shows Chrome, Firefox, and IE which all show a different timezone and accordingly report different times.

[image]

This happens with some desktop applications as well, like Pidgin shows as GMT, but others properly show EDT.

How can I correct this?

Toggling the Windows time settings between manual and automatic seems to have no effect.

Comment: Is the hardware clock OK? Maybe W10 isn't capable of setting the hardware clock of your computer and it must be set from the BIOS setup screen.

Comment: @edumgui thanks for the suggestion. I rebooted and checked bios settings and bios clock shows the correct local time, without a timezone.